# What would be the most correct way to clear L1,L2 and L3 caches in C++?

Tags: c++, caching

I want to run some experiments on an algorithm in order to see how cache efficient it is.

I run the main code of the algorithm on one input several times (iterations), get the values of different counters (branch mispredictions, L2, L3 cache accesses, misses etc) and then after all the iterations are finished I find the average of each counter and return it as an output.

In order for the experiment to be precise, I need to clear the cache before every new iteration.

So the code is looking something like this:

```
main()
   for (it = 0; it < iterations; it++)
        clear_cache();
        run algorithm
        update counters
   return average of all counters
```

Everything is working as expected but I am not very sure about how to do the clearing of the cache properly.

I have found the following method online:

```
void clear_cache(){
   sync();
   std::ofstream ofs("/proc/sys/vm/drop_caches");
   ofs << "3" << std::endl;
   sync();
}
```

However if the total amount of iterations is large, this method takes a lot of time to execute. On the other hand if I completely remove `sync();` the clearing process becomes much faster.

But I have no idea what `sync();` does in practice. Why does everything becomes faster without `sync();`? Do I need this call in order to be sure that all L1,L2 and L3 caches will be clear before each new iteration?

thank you in advance

Comment: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/sysctl/vm.txt The documentation says syncing before drop_cache will minimize the number of dirty caches and more memory will be cleared. There doesn't seem to be a reason to sync twice (before and after write), though.

Comment: As an aside, mention your OS: I assume linux, but you never state it.  A suggestion that probably won't work: Restart the program from scratch?  You could still run into problems where the executable is mapped from disk to memory in an OS-aware way (don't know if linux does this), and the second run uses the same physical ram, and that is in the caches -- so maybe compress the executable into an archive.  Each run unzip it and run it.  Still leaves the possibility that libraries the code uses are in the cache.  So maybe not.

Comment: Assuming this is Linux, see https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cachetlb.txt for how to flush the CPU cache from the kernel. I don't think you can do it in a user program. Your code flushes the kernel caches, not the CPU caches, which is why it's so slow, and why it won't do you any good.

Comment: my cpu is Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-3470 CPU @ 3.20GH and I run my program on Arch. I will research your suggestions, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sync` flushes outstanding file writes. It doesn't affect cached file reads, though. The `drop_caches` method you found online does clear the disk cache, so any future read will also hit the disk.

All this is **unrelated** to L1/2/3 CPU caches. Couldn't be, even. The `sync` function itself will be in L1 cache!

You need assembly code to flush the cache, but you forgot to state which CPU you have.

Comment: my CPU is Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-3470 CPU @ 3.20GH